# Spark consumer streaming from Kafka topic keeps resetting offset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-topic

so I'm running a spark streaming program and reading a stream from a Kafka topic with the following options for the readStream method.

```
options = {
        ...
        ...
        "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
        "startingOffsets": "earliest",
        "maxOffsetsPerTrigger": records_per_trigger,
        "subscribe": topic
        "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
    }
```

I have "startingOffsets"  and "auto.offset.reset" set to earliest but as per the log, it keeps resetting the offset to 142634681. However, it is clearly still consuming messages from the Kafka topic based on the output I am getting so is the log inaccurate? or am I understanding how offsets work wrong?

> Resetting offset for partition edgebook_db_ca_on_history.journal_entries-0 to offset 142634681.

```
23/02/28 20:06:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Cluster ID: lkc-09j5mp
23/02/28 20:06:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Discovered group coordinator b14-pkc-3w22w.us-central1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 (id: 2147483633 rack: null)
23/02/28 20:06:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] (Re-)joining group
23/02/28 20:06:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group.
23/02/28 20:06:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] (Re-)joining group
23/02/28 20:06:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Finished assignment for group at generation 1: {consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1-1f851ea3-4e44-4a9e-b0e3-a5a75d9cbf3d=Assignment(partitions=[edgebook_db_ca_on_history.journal_entries-0])}
23/02/28 20:06:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Successfully joined group with generation 1
23/02/28 20:06:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[edgebook_db_ca_on_history.journal_entries-0])
23/02/28 20:06:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Adding newly assigned partitions: edgebook_db_ca_on_history.journal_entries-0
23/02/28 20:06:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Found no committed offset for partition edgebook_db_ca_on_history.journal_entries-0
23/02/28 20:06:52 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition edgebook_db_ca_on_history.journal_entries-0
23/02/28 20:06:53 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition edgebook_db_ca_on_history.journal_entries-0 to offset 0.
23/02/28 20:06:54 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition edgebook_db_ca_on_history.journal_entries-0
23/02/28 20:06:54 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-379c9446-a679-47c1-bad8-fbf11b3db3e0--1283692680-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition edgebook_db_ca_on_history.journal_entries-0 to offset 142634681.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the way how spark resets the offset to the latest partition, you can take a look at this code and it will help you to understand the way how spark reads the offset. [Kafka offset reader
in spark streaming scenarios](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b11252806d49ed7915744147216db41a747e7d4d/connector/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaOffsetReader.scala)

But is the code always setting the offset to that particular number ? Can you push a single message to kafka topic and check the logs and see if the offsets are getting moved to the latest ones ?

Also, pls take a look at the check point location and go to the offsets folder and see if the offsets are being progressed in a proper way.

Comment: In this case, the offset is the total number of messages in the topic so it’s simply moving the offset all the way to the end.